# Google nearby not working on any device

Tags: google-nearby

We have had google nearby for 4 months with over 20 beacons sending out different messages in different locations but in all that time no one has ever seen a notification and we have never had a click through we can see the beacons being picked up on tools and physical web for the eddistone url but no notifications on any device. can you please help

Comment: I suspect you should ask google this rather.

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried changing your Notification/Incentive?  The devices work best when placed in crowded places.  Remember Bluetooth is affected by water to they will all perform better when placed at least 8 feet off the ground.

There have been glitches recently when using the Google URL shortner - try using a different URL shortner - that may be the issue too.